# hook_install_tasks() in `drush site-install`?

Tags: drush

Does anyone know of a way to add install tasks to `drush site-install`?

I have already added a `hook_install_tasks()` my custom installation profile, but that does not make it into drush when I run `drush site-install`.

**Drupal:** 7.39

**Drush:** 6.0

Comment: Does your installation task run when you install through the web-based installer?  In theory, the result should be the same in Drush as it is in the browser.  Also, you should identify in your question what version of Drupal and Drush you are using.

Comment: It works correctly in the browser, yes. I also added the version of Drupal and Drush I am using in my question as well.